# Resource temporarily unavailable with Rails + Unicorn + Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, scaling, unicorn

I'm running into some issues scaling my rails app running on Unicorn + Nginx. Our traffic has exploded over the last 24 hours and now I'm getting a lot of these errors in my nginx error log:

```
2016/08/01 18:54:51 [error] 13508#0: *50889 connect() to unix:/home/deploy/website/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.158.90.189, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/v1/links.json?referrer=home HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/deploy/website/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock:/api/v1/links.json?referrer=home", host: "website.com", referrer: "http://website.com/"
```

I've tried upping the backlog to 1024 but that hasn't helped at all. Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

nginx default fail_timeout for an upstream configuration is 10s. I guess you hit this margin.